# Invalid/damaged download using send_data with PowerPoint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, powerpoint

I am generating a PowerPoint using the [powerpoint](https://github.com/pythonicrubyist/powerpoint) gem and up until now I was using `send_file`, but now I want to use `send_data`. The reason for this is that `send_data` blocks the application from doing anything else until the call completes, while `send_file` allows the app to continue executing while the file downloads, which sometimes, due to coincidental timing, leads to the file being deleted *before* the user tells their browser to start the download and the web server finishes sending the file and thus a blank or incomplete file is downloaded.

This is how I create my PowerPoint:

```
#Creating the PowerPoint
@deck = Powerpoint::Presentation.new
        
# Creating an introduction slide:    
title = 'PowerPoint'
subtitle = "created by #{username}"
@deck.add_intro title, subtitle
        
blah blah logic to generate slides

# Saving the pptx file.
pptname = "#{username}_powerpoint.pptx"
@deck.save(Rails.root.join('tmp',pptname))
```

Now, on to what I have tried. My first instinct was to call as follows:

```
File.open(Rails.root.join('tmp',"#{pptname}"), 'r') do |f|


send_data f.read, :filename => filename, :type => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint", :disposition => "attachment"
end
```

I've also tried sending the `@deck` directly:

```
    send_data @deck, :filename => pptname, :disposition => "attachment", :type => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"
```

Reading it ends with a larger file than expected and it isn't even able to be opened and sending the `@deck` results in a PowerPoint with one slide that simply has the title: #Powerpoint::Presentation:0x64f0dd0 (aka the powerpoint object).

Not sure how to get the object or file into binary format that `send_data` is looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the file as binary:

```
path = @deck.save(Rails.root.join('tmp',pptname))
File.open(path, 'r', binmode: true) do |f|
  send_data f.read, filename: filename, 
                    type: "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint", 
                    disposition: "attachment"
end
```

This can also be done by calling the `#binmode` method on instances of the file class.

```
send_data @deck, ...
```

Will not work since it calls `to_s` on the object. Since `Powerpoint::Presentation` does not implement a `#to_s` method you're getting the default `Object#to_s`.

Comment: On a side note i'm not sure how prudent it is to use a dead gem that hasn't been updated in 5 years.

Comment: Perfect, that did the trick. I knew from the documentation that it was expecting binary but couldn't figure out how to get it into binary. As for the gem, yeah legacy stuff not much I can do about unfortunately.